# Grouping messages based on date and joining a group

Tags: php, mysql

my problem is pretty complicated, first of all what I want to do: I have been working on a messaging system with groups. I want the dates to kind of group up, for example in discord, it groups the messages only showing the time of day and then it adds the date every time it changes for example :

If there are 1 message from 2020 january 1 and if it is the 2nd then it will show : 2020 january 1 and then it will echo all the messages from that day.

And when a user joins the group, the getmessage() function gets all the messages. So if a user joins the group in 2020 how do I stop them from seeing the messages from 2019 etc...

And how do I find the location of the user to show the date based on their local time.

And how do I make the get messages function to look for more messages once you scroll up?

Here is my code :

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@200&display=swap');
</style>
<?php session_start();
      include_once "../backend/messaging-functions.php";
      foreach (showGroupMembers($_GET['id']) as $auserId) {
        $userid = $auserId['user_id'];
        if ($_SESSION['user-id'] == $userid) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="group-chat" id="groupchat"style=" height: calc(100vh - 175px); position: fixed; overflow:scroll; top:100px; background-color: rgb(47, 49, 54); margin-bottom: 75px;   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;">
      <?php

        foreach (getMessages($_SESSION['user-id'], $_GET['id']) as $message) {
          foreach (transformIdToUsername($message['user_id']) as $usernames) {
          $username = $usernames['username'];
          }
         echo "<h1 style='margin-left: 5px; font-size:20px; color: #c1c1c1; line-height:25px; width:100%;'>{$username} </h1><h2 style='margin-left: 5px; color: #c1c1c1;' >{$message['date_time']}</h2>
         <p style='margin-left: 5px; font-size:20px; line-height:35px; width:100%; margin-bottom: 35px; color: #c1c1c1; white-space: normal;'>{$message['message']}</p> \n";
       }
       ?>
    </div>
    <?php
      echo "<a href='settings.php?id=" . $_GET['id']. "'target= '_blank' style='background-image: url(../images/settings.png); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 50px; width: 50px; position: fixed; top: 25px; right: 25px; z-index: 100;'></a>";
     ?>
    <div id="message_area" class="group-chat" onKeyPress="return detect_message(event)">
      <input type="text" id="message_input" name="message" placeholder="Send message" >
      <input type="hidden" id="group_id" name="group_id" value="<?php echo "{$_GET['id']}";?>">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
} else {
  echo "You ain't a member of this group!";
}
}



 ?>
```

Then :

```
//Runs everytime a key is pressed, only act on keycode = 13, aka "enter"
function detect_message(e) {
  if((e && e.keyCode == 13) || e == 0) {
     //alert("Enter (13) detected!!");
     message  = document.getElementById('message_input').value;
     group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
     send_group_message(message, group_id);
     document.getElementById('message_input').value='';
  }
}

//Browser Support Code
function send_group_message(message, group_id){
    var ajaxRequest; 

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('message',  message);
    data.append('group_id', group_id);
    data.append('sendmessage', 'send'); //Not sure why this is needed by sendmessage.php

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '../backend/sendmessages.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
       if(xhr.status !== 200){
         // Server does not return HTTP 200 (OK) response.
       }
       var objDiv = document.getElementById("groupchat");
       objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
       // Whatever you wanted to do when server responded with HTTP 200 (OK)
    };
    xhr.send(data);
    //trigger page refresh??
}
```

Then :

```
<?php session_start();
  #meant to be called by something like ../frontend/common.js send_group_message

  include_once '../backend/messaging-functions.php';
  include_once '../backend/databaseconn.php';

  $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
  $groupId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['group_id']);
  $date = date("y-m-d h:i:s");
  $myId = $_SESSION['user-id'];

if (isset($_POST['sendmessage'])) {
  if (empty($message)) {
    echo "empty field!";
  } else {
    addMessage($myId, $groupId, $date, $message);
  }
}
```

The functions that send the messages and get the messages :

```
function getMessages($userId, $groupId) {
  global $conn;
  $returnArr = Array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM groups_contents WHERE groups_id =? LIMIT 10";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "There was a problem, please try again";
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $groupId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  }
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($returnArr, $row);
  }

  return $returnArr;
}

function addMessage($userId, $groupId, $time_date, $message) {
  global $conn;
  foreach (showGroupMembers($groupId) as $aMember) {
    $userid = $aMember['user_id'];
    if ($userId == $userid) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO groups_contents (user_id, groups_id, date_time, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
      if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "There was a problem, please try again";
      } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiss", $userId, $groupId, $time_date, $message);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help! I know it's a lot...